# Can somebody help explain what is happening in this fft code snippet

Tags: c, fft, code-snippets

first post here

I have been looking into the fft and in particular the Rosetta Code C implementation
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C

I have been trying to actually understand the code rather than just copy it however I have a problem with a particular line and more specifically a part of the line.

```
_fft(out+step, buf+step, n , step*2);
```

so we have a

```
typedef double complex cplx;
```

then an array of type cplx is declared

```
cplx buf[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

We have step as an int 1

now the problem I am having understanding is what is happening when the int is added to the cplx

so I wrote a test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

typedef double complex cplx;

void test(cplx buff[]) 
{
    for(int a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
        printf("%g \n", creal(buff[a]));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cplx buff[] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0};

    int step = 1;

    test(buff);

    test(buff + step);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

what I get is:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2.1231e-314
```

I cannot make heads or tails of it, I may be missing something pretty fundamental about C99 as I cannot seem to be able to find it on here or by google

Comment: Sorry part of complex.h it gets the real component of buf[] I dont think I actually need it, it doesn't change the output

Comment: You go outside range of *buff* on second call to test. In roseatta code the loop goes from 0 to n, not 0 to 8.

Comment: isn't n = 8 on the rosetta code version?

Comment: Yes, but when you say `buff + step` you do in effect say `for (a = 1; a < 9; ++a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now the problem I am having understanding is what is happening when the int is added to the cplx

Actually the addition is not `<int> + <cplx>` but `<int> + <cplx>*` (in words an integer plus a pointer to a complex). So what you're dealing with here is what's called *pointer arithmetic*. Why a pointer you ask? Because in C array types degrade into a pointer to the array's element type when used in an expression which expects a pointer at its place.

So what is pointer arithmetic?

Well, let' s assume we got an object `a` which is an array of int (the length doesn't matter, as long as we don't access past its boundaries).

```
int a[N];
```

Then pointer arithmetic has been defined that the following three expressions have exactly the same meaning:

```
*(a + i)
a[i]
i[a]
```

Yes, the last one is perfectly valid C, go ahead, try it out.

What does it mean for your code snippet. Well for one thing, when you add 1 to the buffer pointer you pass to `test`, you're adding an offset of one. But since the buffer is only 8 elements long and your `test` function accesses 8 consecutive elements starting from the pointer given it performs an out-of-bounds access which invokes *undefined behavior* any in fact anything may legally happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are calling test twice.  The first time with the address of `buff[0]` and the second time with the address of `buff[step]` where the variable `step` is equal to 1 so it is the same as `buff[1]`.

This is why you are seeing the rotated output with

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I left off the last digit.  The last digit in the second line is just garbage after the end of the array or after the last element of the array `buff`.

buff is an array and if you just specify the name `buff` then it is treated like a pointer.  So in the second call to test you are specifying `&buff[step]` rather than `&buff[0]` which is the same as `buff`.

So `buff[step]` is the same as `*(buff + step)` just as `buff[0]` is the same as `*(buff + 0)` or just `*buff`.  You can either use the braces to do an index or you can do pointer arithmetic.